# Multiple Not Like Statements

Tags: sql, sql-like

Is there an easier(cleaner) way to accomplish the following:

```
AND Prov_Credentialing not like ('%AS%') AND Prov_Credentialing not like ('%CI%')
AND Prov_Credentialing not like ('%DI%') AND Prov_Credentialing not like ('%FQ%')
AND Prov_Credentialing not like ('%EM%') AND Prov_Credentialing not like ('%HS%')
AND Prov_Credentialing not like ('%SN%') AND Prov_Credentialing not like ('%PH%')
AND Prov_Credentialing not like ('%AN%') AND Prov_Credentialing not like ('%RQ%')
```

The Prov_Credentialing column could contain records that have multiple codes.  For example, a column count contain 'AS,ED'.  Therefore, a NOT IN statement wouldn't work because I need to include any code that has the 'AS' in it.

There are MUCH more codes that I need to exclude in the NOT LIKE statement I just listed the first 10 here.

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: I would add the codes you need to exclude into a table, and use a join with that condition. Though this will always perform terribly (and it should perform terribly as is too)

Comment: regular expressions is one way if your DB engine supports it

Answer (score 2):

Store the patterns in a separate table:

```
CREATE TABLE NOT_LIKES (pattern VARCHAR(4));

INSERT INTO NOT_LIKES VALUES ('%AS%');
...

SELECT ...
WHERE  ...
AND    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM NOT_LIKES WHERE Prov_Credentialing LIKE pattern)
```